# New to okhttp3, no idea why it won't show the results on TextView

Tags: java, android, okhttp

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
        final String IMAGE1 = "storage/emulated/0/Download/image_1.jpeg";
        File file1 = new File(IMAGE1);
        try {
            final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG = MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");
            RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("images", "image_1.jpeg",
                            RequestBody.create(file1, MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG))
                    .addFormDataPart("organs", "flower")
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://my-api.plantnet.org/v2/identify/all?api-key=123")
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            textView.setText(response.body().string());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that I'm trying to run a network activity here on the main thread. That's why I included the StrictMode permitAll thing to get around the issue (I saw an answer to a similar topic that suggested doing so). I am trying to use the PlantNet API here and I use my phone for testing. The same phone where the image is saved.

Comment: "That's why I included the StrictMode permitAll thing to get around the issue (I saw an answer to a similar topic that suggested doing so)" -- that is not a very good idea. That is particularly true since you are using OkHttp, which has [a built-in asynchronous HTTP request API](https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#asynchronous-get-kt-java). Beyond that, check Logcat for the stack trace coming from your code, as presumably your code is raising an exception that you are logging there. That could be from missing the `INTERNET` permission or a file access problem.

Comment: that could be it, i have not added a permission for file access.

Answer (score 1):

go see [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

it provides a nice and easy way to make your network calls off the main thread